# Space launches statistics by decade

Tags: discussion, statistics

I do not want to abuse with too many questions of the same type so I ask here if its appropriate to ask a question like:

What were the most busy times in space launches by decade?

most busy days, weeks, months and years.

The 1970 and 1980 were the most busy decades so I think it is interesting to compare with other decades.

Another, unrelated statistics question would be space launches counts by year

Comment: I understand your general caution, you've asked several questions like this and some have been very well-received. So far I don't see any problem and I think you have been very responsive to helpful comments and suggestions. I'm not sure what exactly you are asking here or what kind of answer you are seeking. Can you indicate exactly what your question is?

Comment: examples of your well-received questions: [What was the most busy week in space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45696/12102) and [Most busy times in US space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45715/12102)

Comment: @uhoh - the most busy week în 1980s, then the most busy week în 1990s and so on. Same thing for days months years instead of weeks

Comment: @JoeJobs Maybe it would be a good idea to combine those into one question. Something like: "What was the busiest week of the decade for each decade from 1970s-2010s?" That way people are less likely to get worn out of the same basic question repeated over and over for each decade.

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking about: one question for all decades

Comment: @JoeJobs Yeah, I think that would be fine.

Comment: Thanks i launched the question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/most-busy-times-in-space-launches-by-decade